# the images are not displayed correctly online even it works well locally using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, helper

i created a website by `laravel`, site works fine locally, it displays image if exist, and displays `not-found.jpg` image if image not exist, and when i host it online [aswaktinghir.com][1],always display `not-found.jpg` image, the `productImage` function always goes to the 2nd image condition `not-found.jpg`, even there is an image.

**helpers.php**

```
   function productImage($path) 
{
    return $path && file_exists('storage/'.$path) ? asset('storage/'.$path) : asset('img/not-found.jpg');
}
```

**landing-page.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($annonces as $annonce) 
                        <a href="{{ url('annonces/'.$annonce->id) }}"> 
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="blog-item this-animate" data-animate="fadeInUp">
                                <div class="blog-media">
                                    <img src="{{ asset(productImage($annonce->image) )}}" class="img-responsive" style="width: 240px;height: 240px" /> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-data">
                                    <h5>{{ $annonce->details }}</h5>
                                    <span class="blog-date">{{ $annonce->created_at }} / 0 Comments</span>
                                    <p>{{ substr($annonce->description, 0, 31) }}...</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        @endforeach 
                        </div>
```

Comment: did you create storage symlink?

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko yes ,i create symlink,i edit my function to ` return $path && file_exists('storage/'.$path) ? asset('storage/'.$path) : asset('storage/'.$path);` ,u can see my site again [link](https://aswaktinghir.com)

Comment: did you check the server paths?  does those file exists?

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko some images exist and others are not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git to transfer files to your production server, make sure to take a look in your .gitignore file in the root directory. Make sure you are not excluding the /store or /public/store folders.

Comment: no i use filezilla ,i create symlink,i edit my function to ` return $path && file_exists('storage/'.$path) ? asset('storage/'.$path) : asset('storage/'.$path);` ,u can see my site again [aswak](https://aswaktinghir.com)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
chmod -R 755 [path to storage]
chown -R www-data:www-data [path to storage]
```

Comment: when i run this command its give me error :  `The stream or file "/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied` plz help

Comment: you need to add "sudo" before each command